# ie6 margin expanding by 20px

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-6

i have div's wrapped under div's my html code is.

```
    <div id="content-row">
         <div id="left-box">
              <div id="small-box">
              </div>
              <div id="small-box">
              </div>
              <div id="small-box">
              </div>
              <div id="small-box">
              </div>
        </div>
     </div>
```

and my css is

```
/*content-row*/
#content-row {
    margin: 0 auto!important;
    padding-left:50px;
    width:990px;
    height:320px;
    padding-bottom:20px;    
}
#left-box {
    float:left;
    width:360px;
    height:340px;
}
#small-box {
    width:160px;
    height:150px;
    background-color:#fff;
    float:left;
    margin:0px 20px 20px 0px;
}
```

the above style sheet is exclusively for ie6. my problem is the left-box is taking an extra 20px at the right side. when i have defined the left-box to be 360px; it it taking as 380px;

here is the link to the full code.

http://jsfiddle.net/HXGsT/

what is wrong with the code?

Comment: Change your `id` s to classes. `id` has to be unique within an HTML document.

Comment: @Kyle i am unable to get what you mean to say. can you be precise. i would appreciate if you have any suggestion for me. thank you.

Comment: you have multiple `id="small-box"`; this is not valid HTML. Each `id` attribute in a HTML document must have a different value. See also: http://webdesign.about.com/od/css/f/blfaqmultiIDs.htm

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a known bg in IE6, see this page for more information:
http://www.positioniseverything.net/explorer/doubled-margin.html

Basically, the quick fix is to also add `display: inline;` to the floating element.

Answer (score 2):

In response to your comment:

```
  <div class="content-row">
         <div id="left-box">
              <div class="small-box">
              </div>
              <div class="small-box">
              </div>
              <div class="small-box">
              </div>
              <div class="small-box">
              </div>
        </div>
     </div>


.content-row {
    margin: 0 auto!important;
    padding-left:50px;
    width:990px;
    height:320px;
    padding-bottom:20px;    
}
#left-box {
    float:left;
    width:360px;
    height:340px;
}
.small-box {
    width:160px;
    height:150px;
    background-color:#fff;
    float:left;
    margin:0px 20px 20px 0px;
}
```

The id `#left-box` can be an ID as there is only one of these elements with `id="left-box"` in the document, but because the others are repeated, they must be defined with classes :)

Comment: While not a solution to the question, this is a very valid point to make, and a mistake that I see more and more on the web. As an addition, using ID's for styles is very risky because the only good way to overwrite said styles is with inline CSS on the element.